# How to change the table on admin site?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm new to Django and I would like to change the table that is on the admin site.

Now there is an User class and a Group class, I would like to add my own class, 'Games', to the admin site which have the variables 'name' and 'size'.

The class 'Games' is in my models.py.

How do I do this?

Comment: Have you looked at [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects) for the admin site?

Comment: Or even the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial02/#introducing-the-django-admin) which covers this in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `admin.py` file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *


class Gamesadmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    class Meta:
        model = Games
        fields = ('name','size',)

admin.site.register(Games,Gamesadmin)
```

Do not forget to use your class name correctly . Good Luck.